# pathForResource from URL

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsurl, nsbundle, mainbundle

I have this code:

```
NSString *songPathForm = @"http://www.example.com/file.wav";

NSString *song = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:songPathForm ofType:nil];
```

But song just ends up being null, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your code is passing a URL to a method, to get a path. As you have already the URL, why do you need a path?

Comment: @kiamlaluno I am pulling in audio links with a rss feed to play with AVFoundation framework, I tried playing them just with the NSString songPathForm, but it won't work that way

Answer (score 2):

A 'path' here is meant as a file path on the local file system.  What you're giving to NSBundle is a URL.  NSBundle is typically used to get files which are in the application itself  (What you see when you select 'Show Package Contents' from the Finder).  NSBunlde is expecting a *relative* file path also, not an absolute path (because you don't know where the app is).

Answer (score 1):

The `pathForResource` method works only for files inside a bundle. If you want to access a file at a external URL you could use `dataWithContentsOfURL:` in the `NSData` class for example.

Comment: When I use this:

                NSData* song = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:songPathForm]];

I get a bunch of crap being outputted, like 004d0000 000e00004 and stuff

Comment: @Matt That is not crap; it's the content of the file.

Comment: It doesn't work though, I am using this to play a music file, that NSData cannot be played

Comment: Ok, I think you should do a little research before asking. I don't know what you are using to play the sound, but if you use `AVAudioPlayer` you can make use of the `initWithData:error:` method that will play a sound stored in a `NSData`.

Answer (score 0):

To play a sound for which you know the URL, you should use code similar to the following one:

```
NSSound *sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:songPathForm] byReference:NO];
[sound play];
```